# How to avoid multiple service objects when using a json service in a web2py module?

Tags: web2py

So a bit of setup. In web2py you can simply decorate a controller function to expose it as a json service, like so:

```
def call():
    return service()

@service.json
def do_something():
    return "blah"
```

Then you can call it (like in an ajax request) like "call/json/do_something" and you will get "blah", formatted in json.

You can do this in a class in a module, like so:

```
 from gluon.tools import Service
 service = Service()

 class SomeClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    @service.json
    def do_something():
       return "blah"
```

So in your controller you can do this:

```
 import mymodule

 def m_call():
     return mymodule.service()

 def call():
     return service()

 @service.json
 def do_another_thing():
     return "blee"
```

And then in a view, I can call either service, such as "m_call/json/do_something" or "call/json/do_another_thing". This works, BUT I have multiple ways to call json services now. There is an upside to this, that the module services are scoped differently, but at least in certain circumstances I want to be able to do something like this in my controller:

```
 import mymodule

 def call():
    # This obviously does NOT work, but shows what I WANT to do
    service.merge_with(mymodule.service) 

    return service()
```

The result is that ALL of my services (or whichever ones I want) are exposed in a single service object, and can be called with the same syntax, regardless where the function is location in my application. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator simply adds the function to a dictionary, which is stored in an attribute of the `Service` object. So, in theory you should just be able to merge the dictionary of the module's service object with the dictionary of the service object defined in the model file. I haven't tried it, but something like this might work:

```
import mymodule

def call():
    service.json_procedures.update(mymodule.service.json_procedures)
    return service()
```

You could write a function that takes a set of service objects and merges them all.

Note, the attribute name `json_procedures` is an internal implementation detail, not part of the public API, so this isn't guaranteed to remain backward compatible.

A similar approach should work with the other types of services (via `service.xml_procedures`, etc.).

Comment: Wow, that works great! Thanks Anthony. And yeah, from this example I see that it would be easy to update a specific subset of the service objects.